# Python - ctypes.c_char.from_buffer vs ctypes.c_void_p(string)

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, kernel32, memmove

What would be the difference between:

```
pointer = ctypes.c_char_p('abc')
```

and

```
string = 'abc'
buffer = (ctypes.c_char * len(string)).from_buffer(string)
```

Technically both are pointers when passed in their respective function calls like such: (cross platform different function calls)

```
if os.name == 'posix':
    string = 'abc'
    libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')

    # creating a pointer pointing at our string
    s_ptr = ctypes.c_char_p(string)

    # allocating free space
    free_space_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.valloc(ctypes.c_int(len(string))))

    # copying memory from one loc to another
    ctypes.memmove(free_space_ptr, s_ptr, ctypes.c_int(len(string)))

else:
    string = 'abc'

    # allocating free space
    free_space_ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(...)

    # creating a pointer pointing at our string?
    buffer = (cytpes.c_char_p * len(string))).from_buffer(string)

    # copying memory from one loc to another
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ctypes.c_void_p(free_space_ptr), buffer, ctypes.c_int(len(shellcode)))
```

**My Question is:**

The two function calls (both memmove, and RtlMoveMemory) take in two pointers ==> destination, source, and then the last param is the length to copy.

***What is the difference in the two ways of getting a pointer that points to our string?***:

- Using ctypes.c_char_p(string)

vs

- Using ctypes.c_char.from_buffer(string)

Comment: One difference is `ctypes.c_void_p('abc')` doesn't work :^)  I don't see the point of this code.  I think `create_string_buffer()` would do the same thing as this OS-specific code.

Comment: Oh yeah it should be ctypes.c_char_p(string), fixed in the edit. But do you think if these ways can be used on the other platform? eg. Using ctypes.c_char_p(string) and passing it into the ms api RtlMoveMemory function as the source param, I wonder if that will work...

Comment: thanks btw @Mark, just cant upvote b/c not enough reps, but yeah create_string_buffer() would also be a great way to create a buffer of  char pointer which is just a char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, it can be concluded that

First:

```
ctypes.c_char.from_buffer(string)
```

wouldn't work because the from_buffer method accepts a param that is an array of bytes, so I would need to convert string into array of bytes first like such:

```
buf = bytearray(string)
ptr = ctypes.c_char.from_buffer(string)
```

***now both returned results of:***

```
ctypes.c_char_p(string)
```

and

```
ctypes.c_char.from_buffer(buf)
```

*can be used in memory copying operation function calls like:*

```
ctypes.memmove for linux
```

and

```
RtlMemoryMove for windows
```